# PHP Notice: Undefined index in $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I have been trying to complete the server-side script for my web-app and have come across a problem I can't seem to resolve.

I am using GET requests to send/recieve data from the server. Up until I implemented the last GET request the code was working fine. Now i have `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: role` in my error log and I cannot work out why.

Here is the PHP server-side code.

```
$handler = new XMLHandler();
if ($_GET["ajax"] == "true") {#fn - Function
    if($_GET["fn"] == "init"){
    }elseif($_GET["fn"] == "cou"){
        echo $handler->toJSON($handler->getCourses());
    }elseif($_GET["fn"] == "mod"){
        echo $handler->toJSON($handler->getModules($_GET["data"]));
    }elseif($_GET["fn"] == "filt"){
        $breakdown = explode(":", $_GET["role"]);//breakdown the roleString from the client side into an Array
        echo $handler->toJSON($handler->getCoursesByRole($breakdown[1]));
    }
}
```

And here is the JQuery AJAX call

```
var data = {
  "fn" : "filt",
  "ajax" : "true",
  "role" : roleString
};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: SERVICE_URL, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var i, list = "";
        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            console.log(response[i]);
            list += formatListItem(response[i]);
        }
        $("#cList").html(list).listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

}

`roleString` looks like this: `core:false:false`

If anybody can offer any advice or help I would really appreciate it.

a var_dump of $_GET gives me this:

```
array(3) {
  ["fn"]=>
  string(4) "filt"
  ["ajax"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["role"]=>
  string(34) "adultScotland:projectM:false:false"
}
[]
```

Comment: Is the "undefined index" error in relation to the $breakdown = explode(":", $_GET["role"]); line of the PHP file, or is it another PHP file? What happens if you var_dump($_GET); ?

Comment: yes, the error is in relation to the $breakdown line. I have no idea what var_dump($_GET) does but i'll go try that now

Comment: Since you are doing it via AJAX it gets a little more complicated to debug it. You want to see what `$_GET` looks like, but you'll probably have to do something like this: `$fn = fopen("errors.txt", "a"); fwrite($fn, print_r($_GET, true)); $fclose($fn);` and then go look at the `errors.txt` file.

Comment: i updated the question with the results from var_dump($_GET);

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` is inappropriate for your usage

Comment: @charlietfl thanks but this still doesn't fix the problem :/

Answer (score -1):

Use if statement before expload

```
if($_GET['role']) {
    explode(":", $_GET["role"]);
}
```

You are checking all other GET vars but not this one

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't resolve an area of confusion. i don't understand why the code can't find `$_GET("role");`

Comment: with the if statement, it irradicates the error bur doesn't solve the problem

Comment: actually, this doesn't irradicate the error. i'd just looked over the error log without seeing it. instead this tells me it cannot find: `_GET`

Comment: @JamieMcAllister have you checked it without AJAX?

Comment: I assume you mean typing the data into the address bar. I just did that there and didn't get any errors